# Can the `linky` filter be used with text containing html tags?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html, ngsanitize

From the [linky docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky) it seems it should work with `ng-bind-html`. However, if the text contains html tags, then `linky` overrides the actual html interpretation to transform URLs into links.

This can be seen by for instance writing

```
Pretty text with some links:<br/><img src="http://something.com/lol.gif">
http://angularjs.org/,
mailto:us@somewhere.org,
another@somewhere.org,
and one more: ftp://127.0.0.1/.
```

in the example at the bottom of the [linky docs page](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky).

Is there a way to firstly sanitise and interpret html using `ng-bind-html` and only later parse the resulting text to add clickable links?